# Avoid folders in Resources folder from being build or compile

Tags: python, build, titanium, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile

I am building a Titanium mobile project.

I have some folders with some .JS files in the Resources folder. The problem I ran into is that I need to exclude some of the folder while building for iphone but those folder are needed in my android build.

I looked into the python files in the SDK folder and found out that there are separate file i.e. `builder.py` for iphone and android.

While building for android or ios all of my JS files gets build, which i dont want as it increases my app size.

As for now i have successfully edited the `builder.py` file so that it copies the selected folder into my iphone resources folder. It runs fine on simulator but when i tried running on the device i got error saying .js file missing.
I know that my copied .Js files were not archived

Can anyone help me in configuring that `builder.py` so that we can exclude some folders from getting build.

Answer (score 0):

Ajeet, I believe you can create a directory for android and iphone inside the resources folder  that you can keep your platform-specific code/assets in.  I think the compiler recognizes this.

Comment: i know compiler recognizes it but what if i keep the .js files  in any other folder apart form android or iphone folder.

Comment: hmm, not sure of anyway to ignore those. I use logic to determine the OS with Titanium.Platform.osname and write platform specific code inside there.